# How can I split a string into an array?

Tags: php, string, preg-split

I try to split my string into an array. All strings between the calculation signs `+/*-`:

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,-]*[+-*]+/", "quanity*price/2+tax");
```

This is what I try to achieve:

```
Array
(
    [0] => quantity
    [1] => price
    [1] => tax
)
```

But the result is an empty string.

Comment: Do you mean splitting on `[-*\/+\d]+` https://regex101.com/r/3NEEfc/1 You could move the `-` to the beginning/end of the character class or escape it `\-`

Comment: oh, this is the website I really need. Thank you

Comment: No, but the fourth bird was offering it without asking

Comment: why not explode + str_replace here??

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tested your code. it is working, but not, if I try this line "quanity*price/2" . Then I get one empty value in my array

Comment: @devpro I read in a tutorial that explode is not working with multiple characters `+/*-`

Comment: @peace_love That is because of the split. There is a match but nothing on the right so it will be empty. What is the expected result / behaviour?

Comment: This is the output: `array:3 [▼
  0 => "quanity"
  1 => "price"
  2 => ""
]`  This is expected: `array:3 [▼
  0 => "quanity"
  1 => "price"
]`

Comment: @peace_love You could do it like this https://3v4l.org/dmdHP

Comment: `[+-*]` means a range of charscters, not three literal characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pattern you tried the second character class is not matching a digit and the hyphen should be escaped or placed at the beginning/end.

You could use a single character class instead. If you change the delimiter to other than `/` like `~` you don't have to escape the forward slash.

```
[-*\/+\d]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bp8USG/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/As7Wi)

For example

```
$strings = [
    "quanity*price/2+tax",
    "quanity*price/2"
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    $keywords = preg_split("~[-*/+\d]+~", $string,  -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    print_r($keywords);
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => quanity
    [1] => price
    [2] => tax
)
Array
(
    [0] => quanity
    [1] => price
)
```

If you also want to match 0+ preceding whitespace chars, comma's:

```
[\s,]*[-*/+\d]+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X1zjxa/1)

Answer (score 2):

This will split the string where any of these exist: +/* and create an array out of it:

```
$string = "quanity*price/2+tax";  
$str_arr = preg_split ("/[-*\/+\d]+/", $string);  
print_r($str_arr);
```

Posted code with your example for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Using the regex that The fourth bird recommended:

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[-*\/+\d]+/", "quanity*price/2+tax", -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` should drop empty values (https://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

Comment: The result of your answer: `array:1 [▼
  0 => "quanity*price/2+tax"
]`

Comment: Great catch, @peace_love. I'd missed the optional third parameter in `preg_split` and misplaced the flag. I've updated my answer to include `-1` for the $limit parameter, to specify no limit. I could have also passed `0` or `null`.